# Can we implement time-based rekeying in Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

We have a requirement for our SSH client (Paramiko) to implement time-based rekeying i.e, rekeying has to be done when the session exceeds more than one hour.

This feature is not seen in Paramiko which we use for SSH clients. Is there a way to implement this using Paramiko?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own timer, and once per hour call:

```
SSHClient.get_transport().packetizer._trigger_rekey()
```